# Weird return error in scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, types, return

```
def f: (Int, Int) => (Int, Int) => List[Int] = {
  (x, y) => (a, b) => 
    //do anything
    if(y == 5)
      return List(a, x)
    // do something else
}
```

When I use this, Intellij says:

> type mismatch; 
>   found :List[Int] 
>   required: (Int, Int) => (Int, Int) => List[Int] 
>   return List(a,x)

If I do the same, without return (which wouldn't work, if there is code after it), there is no error. Why does the return need this type?

Comment: why do you expect "do something else" to be reached if it follows a "return" statement?

Comment: Oh sorry, there should be an if statement.